# What is model.cov_params() in statsmodels?

Tags: statsmodels, covariance, glm, covariance-matrix

I am unable to understand what the [cov_params][1] from a fitted statsmodel represents. I thought it would be the covariance matrix of the data but that does not seem to be the case. It is not even scale*convariance_matrix_of_the_data

I have used the following code snippet to try to understand:

A random dataset preparation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'num1':np.random.randn(30,),
                   'num2':np.random.randn(30,),
                  'labels':np.random.choice([1,0],30)})
```

Computing covariance matrix on it:

```
df.drop('labels',axis=1).cov()
output:
        num1        num2
num1    0.810012    0.082823
num2    0.082823    0.866951
```

computing the cov_params() from the model:

1. Fitting the model:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
mod = sm.formula.glm(formula = "labels ~ num1+num2",\
              data = df,
             family = sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
```

scale is 1.0:

```
mod.scale
output
1.0
```

Getting cov_params:

```
mod.cov_params()
output:
            Intercept   num1        num2
Intercept   0.162491    0.006924    0.006894
num1        0.006924    0.234236    0.004327
num2        0.006894    0.004327    0.198648
```

As you can see the cov values between num1 and num2 are not the same in the two cav matrices. They are not even a scaled version of each other by `mod.scale` parameter as `mod.scale` is 1.0

Can you help me understand what is `mod.cov_params()`
[1]: https://www.statsmodels.org/0.8.0/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.cov_params.html

Comment: It is the estimated covariance matrix of the estimated parameters. The square root of the diagonal contains the standard errors of the parameters.